# Is it possible to start a pthread immediately without using SIGHUP?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pthreads, signals

Is it possible to immediately start a thread that is created by `pthread_create` without waiting ~300us for it to start? Right now the existing code is doing a "kick start" of the thread by sending a `SIGHUP` to the thread, however, the side effect is that if the main process did not setup a signal handler for `SIGHUP`, the process would just quit...

I can make it handle the `SIGHUP`, however I'm wondering if there is a better solution than doing it this way...

Note: the initial version of the question said "300ms", leading to comments that 300milliseconds is ridiculously long.  300microseconds is much more plausible.

Comment: three hundred milliseconds? are you sure? can you post a working example?

Comment: Did you mean microseconds?

Comment: Can't post it, well it might not necessarily be 300ms, but the existing code did went through 300-ish iteration of a waiting loop, however when you send a SIGHUP, the function being pass to the `pthread_create` is start immediately.

Comment: Ahh.... ' waiting loop' :((

Comment: I used `pthread_create` many times, but never with `SIGHUP` signal, so I guess the answer is yes.

Comment: @codenamezero Are you running on a single core system ? I'd try calling sched_yield() right after pthread_create() to see if that switches to the new thread more quickly. In any case 300ms for the new thread to start runnign is not normal in any case, so there must be more to your code or platform that what's ordinaery.

Comment: Agree with nos. Even on a multicore system, the creating thread shouldn't be using CPU to wait for the new thread. That's counterproductive. Yielding is a quick hack, `SIGHUP` is a weird and problematic way to yield, doing a blocking wait is the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

After tinkering it for a couple more hours, another way to archive what I needed. BTW, I tried using `sched_yield` as @nos suggested, and that didn't yield any different behaviour.

As an update, I want to point out that the code I was working with were doing a `do...while` loop to probe whether the pthread is finished or not by sending a `SIGHUP`.

The solution to my question is to send a custom `sigaction` like the following:

Have a dummy signal handler:

```
void thread_signal_handler(int sig) { }
```

Then in my library that I was working with, before sending out the `SIGHUP`:

```
...
struct sigaction sa;
sa.sa_handler = dummy_handler;
sa.sa_flags = 0;
sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
sigaction(SIGHUP, &sa, NULL);
pthread_kill(tid, SIGHUP);
...
```

Doing it like this, my application don't need to handle the `SIGHUP` signal.

Comment: Why are you using `SIGHUP`, instead of a signal that's non-fatal by default?  If `SIGCONT`, or `SIGCHLD`, or `SIGURG` still solve your problem, you wouldn't have to set them as ignored.  `SIGCONT`'s default action is to resume from stopped, while according to `signal(7)`, SIGCHLD and SIGURG are both ignored by default.  Ignoring `SIGHUP` means your program will keep running in some cases when people would expect it to exit if they had it in the background when they logged out.